# How to implement client code for the getting jar which is generated by wsdl2Java by CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, apache2, client-side, stubs

I am new to Webservice.  I got `xxxService.wsdl` file from my client. I have generated jar using the following command with apache CXF:

```
wsdl2java.bat -V  -d com\xxxx\service\sso -clientjar xxxwsservice.jar  xxxTokenWebService.wsdl.
```

Now i got the jar. I am using  `apache-cxf-2.7.6`, `jdk1.6.0_37` and `jboss-eap-5.1.2`. My doubt is how to write the client code. Means which class is starting point to invoke the service. Is there any configuration for credentials, timeout, content type and content length.

Please advise me to implement the client.

Answer (score 0):

You create the stub using wsdl2java and develop your client using the stub created.

```
./wsdl2java.sh -uri ~/Desktop/xxxxx.wsdl
```